# How to display user comments dynamically to html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I am working on a website and it includes a comment section at the bottom part of it. I developed an "Add comment" button which stores the comment into firebase firestore. However, I'm struggling with how to display the comments on my website. I know how to fetch all the comments from firestore but I don't how to display them in my website. I have searched for hours on google but didn't quite find what I want so any help is appreciated.

So, I've got an input for the comment and a button to submit it:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Comment"
      id="comment"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />

<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-dark"
    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
    onclick="postComment()"
     >
     Comment
</button>
```

And a function to post it firebase firestore:

```
function postComment() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  let db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection("comments")
    .add({
      name,
      comment,
      time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And that's how I get the data from firestore:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Now all I want to know is a dynamic way of displaying comments on my website. In other words a comment section layout/model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Can you get the data? The problem is just showing them? or how to consume it and show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet represents a basic idea. Please let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
const comments = [
  {
    name: 'Author 1',
    comment: 'Comment from author 1.'
  },
  {
    name: 'Author 2',
    comment: 'Comment from author 2.'
  }
];

const target = document.getElementById('target');

function displayComments(target, comments) {
  comments.forEach((comment) => {
    const element = document.createElement('span');
    element.classList.add('comment');
    element.innerText = `${comment.name} says: ${comment.comment}`;
    target.appendChild(element);
  });
}

displayComments(target, comments);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.comment {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='target' class='container'></div>
```

Comment: One more thing. Can you recommend a way so that the last span element is on top? In another words, the last comment on top.

Comment: @NabilTheCoder Yes, just reorder your array using `Array.sort(...)` before passing it to the display function or if it is already ordered, change `target.appendChild` with `target.prepend` so items will be added in reverse (or just reverse the array).